# how is this.checked working in this code?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How this.checked in this code being calculated here? code is working perfectly the way it should 
be, i'm just not getting the logic.

```
<p>Select All :
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
</p>
<p>
    Item 1:
    <input type="checkbox" class="children" value="item1">Item 2:
    <input type="checkbox" class="children" value="item2">Item 3:
    <input type="checkbox" class="children" value="item3">
</p>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectAll').click(function () {
        $('.children').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdkQ2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this.checked` gives you true or false which is used to set the `checked` property of all the elements with class children. If select All is selected this.checked will give `true` and `false` otherwise.

To understand this consider the condition you put on this.checked and set the `checked` property to `true` when checked and `false` when not checked.

```
if(this.checked)
    $('.children').prop('checked', true);
else
    $('.children').prop('checked', false);
```

Or simply without condition

```
$('.children').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you click `#selectAll` you set the same value to all children. `this.checked` returns the value of `#selectAll` checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `this.checked` is just basically used to retrieve the checked state of your input with id `selectAll`.

It will return `true` or `false` then based on this value, it will set the checked state of your `input` with class `children`.

So if `selectAll` checked, all `.children` will be checked and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

when selectAll is clicked then all checkboxes which have children class are set to values of selectAll values.

That means if selectAll is clicked then all children class checkboxs are checked if selectAll is checked  or unchecked if selectAll is unchecked.